# how can i fix expected indented block on cmd

Tags: python, block

I'm trying to run hello.py under CMD but when I run the flask I get this error below, how can I fix it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6RNL.png)

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn how to use code block so you don't have to use image to display code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to indent the `return 'Hello World!'` line in your `hello.py` file.

```
from flask import *
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

Should at least allow it to compile

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: ok, fixed that part, now it says line 1, in <module> from flask import flask import error: cannot import name flask, what's this?

Comment: Change from flask import flask to from flask import *

Comment: you mean like this?  from flask import 
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
 return 'Hello, World!'                   it says invalid syntax line 1

Comment: No worries. Keep coding!

Comment: @NatalieMcKnight if the reply solves your issue, press the gray tick at left side to mark it accepted answer